# Why would Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict() be missing?

Tags: python, python-module, biopython

I'm trying to see how much "header" info I can get out of a PDB file, following the hints at [The Biopython Structural Bioinformatics FAQ](http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ). I'm led to use the mmCIF version.  but there seems something odd about the package/egg:

```
>>> from Bio.PDB import *
>>> cifFile = '.../path2/3VQ8.cif'
>>> mmcif_dict = MMCIF2Dict(cifFile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MMCIF2Dict' is not defined
```

I get a different error if I fully qualify the class:

```
>>> import Bio.PDB
>>> mmcif_dict = Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict(cifFile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MMCIF2Dict'
```

Note that most of Bio.PDB works as I expect:

```
>>> parser=PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)
>>> inf = '.../path2/3NF8.pdb'
>>> structure=parser.get_structure('3Nf8',inf)
>>> structure.header.keys()
['structure_method', 'head', 'journal_reference', 'compound',
 'name', 'author', 'deposition_date', 'release_date', 'source',
 'resolution', 'structure_reference']
```

and I have a recent version:

```
>>> Bio.__version__
'1.61'
```

which *does* have the `MMCIF2Dict.py` file is inside the Bio egg, but `MMCIF2Dict` isn't in the module:

```
>>> dir(Bio.PDB)
['AbstractPropertyMap', 'Atom', 'CaPPBuilder', 'Chain', 'DSSP', 'Dice',
 'Entity', 'ExposureCN', 'FragmentMapper', 'HSExposure', 'HSExposureCA',
 'HSExposureCB', 'Model', 'NeighborSearch', 'PDBExceptions', 'PDBIO',
 'PDBList', 'PDBParser', 'PPBuilder', 'Polypeptide', 'Residue',
 'ResidueDepth', 'Select', 'Selection', 'Structure',
 'StructureAlignment', 'StructureBuilder', 'Superimposer', 'Vector',
 '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__',
 '__path__', 'calc_angle', 'calc_dihedral', 'extract', 'get_surface',
 'is_aa', 'm2rotaxis', 'make_dssp_dict', 'mmCIF', 'parse_pdb_header',
 'refmat', 'rotaxis', 'rotaxis2m', 'rotmat', 'standard_aa_names',
 'to_one_letter_code', 'vector_to_axis']
```

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Something seems a little strange to me about its import structure.  Could you try `from Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict import MMCIF2Dict`?

Comment: @DSM, it's due to the lack of an explicit import of `MMCIF2Dict` in `__init__.py` (so your suggested import will work just fine, but `from Bio.PDB import *` will not import `MMCIF2Dict` into the namespace).

Comment: @DavidCain: that's not what's puzzling me: in my version of BioPython (1.61), `MMCIFParser` is *not* imported, because the `except` triggers.

Comment: Hm. That is perplexing. I'm also on 1.61, but have no such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the answer in [`Bio.PDB`'s `__init__.py`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/__init__.py).

In short, `from Bio.PDB import *` imports everything in `__init__.py`'s namespace. If you read `__init__.py`, you can see that [it imports `MMCIFParser`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/8be2402b8424722121d14c286b62bf70e8befde9/Bio/PDB/__init__.py#L19), but *not* `MMCIF2Dict` (at least not directly): [`MMCIFParser` imports `MMCIF2Dict`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/8be2402b8424722121d14c286b62bf70e8befde9/Bio/PDB/MMCIFParser.py#L16) and makes use of it there.

So, if you do `from Bio.PDB import MMCIF2Dict; mmcif_dict = MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict(cifFile)`, it should work without complaint. However, `from Bio.PDB import *` won't put `MMCIF2Dict` into the current namespace.

Comment: effbot's summary of [Python's import behavior](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) should help clear up exactly what's going on with each `import` statement.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that using `from <module> import *` is generally [frowned upon](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

Comment: @DSM, your `from Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict import MMCIF2Dict` works just fine.  David, `from Bio.PDB import MMCIF2Dict` works, but only with a fully-qualified call to `MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict(cifFile)`.  i'm happy to credit either of you with an answer if you can edit to refelect this?  (and yes, i know `from foo import *` is a no-no, i was just trying to play around with namespaces to see wazzup:)  thanks gentlemen!

Comment: @rikb, `from Bio.PDB import MMCIF2Dict` will import the _module_, not the class. Your "fully-qualified" call is just accessing the class `MMCIF2Dict` within the module. If you want the class, you can then do `MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict` as you've done, or you could do `from Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict import MMCIF2Dict`.