# Bio.PDB mmcif2dict module not callable

Tags: python, header, sequence, biopython, protein-database

I fetched a cristal structure of a protein using the function retrieve_pdb_file from Bio.PDB. The default format has changed from PDB to PDBx/mmCif. I want to extract the protein sequence from the header in the cif file. There is supposed to  be a simple function in Bio.PDB called MMCIF2Dict to do this but the module is not callable. I also downloaded the cif file manually and put it in the script folder but still the same error. My biopython is up to date. Am I doing something wrong or the module is not well implemented? Thank you for your answers.

```
from Bio.PDB import *

cifFile = '1bu7.cif'
mmcif = MMCIF2Dict(cifFile)
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict() be missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383747/why-would-bio-pdb-mmcif2dict-be-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module is well implemented. The problem with your code is that you are calling a **module** instead of a **function**. In your particular case the module and the function have the same names hence the confusion.

To solve that you need to fix your code as follows:

```
from Bio.PDB import *

cifFile = '1bu7.cif'
mmcif = MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict(cifFile)
```

Comment: @warrilord If you think the reply answers your question you might consider accepting it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict import MMCIF2Dict
```

Instead of :

```
from Bio.PDB import *
```

Comment: No problem! Happy coding (: